# Vlookup in two different areas across a column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, vlookup

I have a worksheet (Sheet 1) that contains a help column AR that contains the number "5" or text "Invalid". I want column AS to do a specific vlookup if AR contains the number "5", but if it contains the text "invalid" to do a separate specific vlookup. Currently what I have just overwrites to what is done in the else section of my loop to be the last iteration over the column and just ends up doing a vlookup for one or the other. I'm using column Y in sheet 1 as the specific value (aCell) that is being used to vlookup. Any help would go a long way, thanks!

```
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Set wsThis = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim wsAnd As Worksheet
Set wsAnd = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LastRow As Long, myRng As Range
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count
With wsIt
    For x = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AR$" & x) = "5" Then
            For Each aCell In wsIt.Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow)
                .Cells(aCell.Row, 45) = "Not Found"
                On Error Resume Next
                .Cells(aCell.Row, 45) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                aCell.Value, wsThis.Range("$B$2:$Q$400"), 5, False)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next aCell
        End If
    Next
End With

With wsIt
    For x = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AR$" & x) = "Invalid" Then
            For Each aCell In wsIt.Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow)
                .Cells(aCell.Row, 45) = "Not Found"
                On Error Resume Next
                .Cells(aCell.Row, 45) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                aCell.Value, wsAnd.Range("$B$2:$Q$400"), 5, False)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next aCell
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand well, but couldn't you just use Excel formula and `IF` function? Is it performance issue?

Comment: @brainac I just wanted this to be performed using VBA because it gets iterated over a series of rows that is dynamically changing. In this instance its 400 but it could be more in other scenarios. I'm currently trying a work around that will place a "Not Found" in the second with loop in a dummy column that way my contents from the first with loop are not overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly intended your aim, you could:

- use Application.VlookUp() method to benefit from its returned value capture any error and query it
- use a Select Case block to formerly choose the lookUp range in relation with column “AR” value

  ```
  Dim wsIt As Worksheet
  Set wsIt = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Dim wsThis As Worksheet
  Set wsThis = Sheets("Sheet3")
  Dim wsAnd As Worksheet
  Set wsAnd = Sheets("Sheet2")
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim aCell As Range
  Dim lookUpResult As Variant

  LastRow = wsThis.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  With wsIt
      For x = 2 To LastRow
          Select Case .Cells(x, "AR") 
              Case "5"
                  Set VLookUpRng = wsThis.Range("$B$2:$Q$400")
              Case “Invalid”
                  Set VLookUpRng = wsAnd.Range("$B$2:$Q$400")
              Case Else
                  Set VLookUpRng = Nothing
          End Select

          If Not VLookUpRng Is Nothing Then
              For Each aCell In .Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow)
                  lookUpResult = Application.VLookup( aCell.Value, VLookUpRng, 5, False)
                  .Cells(aCell.Row, 45) = IIf(IsError(lookUpResult),  "Not Found", lookUpResult)
              Next
          End If
      Next
  End With
  ```

Comment: This is a far better solution than the roundabout method I used, thanks @DisplayName

Comment: I just tried running this in another part of my code but was thrown the error overflow for Not Found. I'm confused as to why that would happen but essentially in wsThis contains 380 iterations of those that contain case "5" and in wsAnd contains 30 iterations of those that contain case "Not Found" could the range that I'm adding be causing the issue?

Comment: Which line is throwing that error and what’s the value of relevant variables at that line?

Comment: Case “Invalid”
                Set VLookUpRng = wsAnd.Range("$B$2:$Q$400") this was throwing the error and the value of VlookupRng was 20

Comment: I can’t understand neither how that line is throwing that error (since it simply sets a finite Range) nor how that range has a value of 20 (since it’s a range of 399 cells). You must be mistaken: take a closer look!

Answer (score 0):

This wasnt a great solution but essentially I pasted over the vlookup results of the 2nd iteration into a new sheet and then sorted the columns of sheet 1 and sheet 2 such that the results would reference each other correctly.

```
Dim x as Long
Dim y As Long
Dim LastRow
Dim NewLast
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    NewLast = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For x = 2 to LastRow 
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AS$" & x) = "Not Found" Then
        For y = 2 To NewLast
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AS$" & x) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$F$" & y)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$AT$" & x) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$F$" & y)
        Next
    End If
Next
```